# Is it possible to set iOS notifcations for certain apps ON / OFF depening on day / time?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

We use Trello (Kanban project management / collaboration app) allot at work, every one has it set up on their iPhones.

When a person is mentioned / contacted in the app they get an iOS notification / alert, this is fine during working hours, but over the weekend / late at night i guess this gets quite irritating.

Is there a way that an end user can put select app notifications 'to sleep' for certain hours of the day / days of the week ?

Answer (score 1):

Not select apps, no. Do Not Disturb can block notifications globally between certain times of the day, but this cannot be applied to single apps only.